# Conflicting requests after update to CentOS 9 Stream from 8

Tags: centos, dnf

I have a CentOS 8 system that I have decided to upgrade to CentOS 9 and this is not offically supported. I did however find some directions on doing this a few pages into a Google search [on Github](https://gist.github.com/yodermk/9c8081a70ec4e0f2ffca8d6c3603da32). These directions have mostly worked and I have booted into the new system with the new kernel. There however remains an issue that shows every time that I use the package manager `dnf` to do anything.

These are the errors I am getting now when running `dnf upgrade`...

```
# dnf upgrade
error: /usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/macros.php74-config: line 3: Macro %undefine is a built-in (%define)
error: /usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/macros.php74-config: line 3: Macro %undefine is a built-in (%define)
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Last metadata expiration check: 0:27:27 ago on Thu 17 Mar 2022 13:25:04.
Modular dependency problems:

 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module composer:2:20220317110346:00000000.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module container-tools:rhel8:8060020211019153644:2e213529.x86_64
 Problem 3: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module httpd:2.4:8050020211112043353:b4937e53.x86_64
 Problem 4: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module mariadb:10.3:8030020210419150013:30b713e6.x86_64
 Problem 5: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module nginx:1.14:8000020211221191913:55190bc5.x86_64
 Problem 6: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module perl:5.26:8000020190628020724:55190bc5.x86_64
 Problem 7: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module perl-DBD-MySQL:4.046:8030020200716171139:3a70019f.x86_64
 Problem 8: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module perl-DBI:1.641:8030020200716150652:1e4bbb35.x86_64
 Problem 9: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module perl-IO-Socket-SSL:2.066:8040020200924212038:1aedcbfe.x86_64
 Problem 10: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module perl-libwww-perl:6.34:8040020211102170116:bf75fe78.x86_64
 Problem 11: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module php:remi-7.4:20220317110346:00000000.x86_64
 Problem 12: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module python36:3.6:8050020210825152031:982725ab.x86_64
 Problem 13: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module ruby:2.5:8050020210527144607:b4937e53.x86_64
 Problem 14: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module subversion:1.10:8030020210222042748:9ce6d490.x86_64
 Problem 15: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module varnish:6:8050020211109225449:b4937e53.x86_64
 Problem 16: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(platform:el8) needed by module virt:rhel:8060020220208213251:d63f516d.x86_64
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I tried removing all the packages mentioned above and installing them again but it did not change anything here. I am not really sure what to do to proceed.

Edit: I removed the package rhc and updated the above output to only show the conflicting requests issue I am having.

Below is the module list from `dnf modules list`...

```
composer             2 [e]        common   Dependency Manager for PHP                                                    
container-tools      rhel8 [e]    common   Most recent (rolling) versions of podman, buildah, skopeo, runc, conmon, runc,
                                            conmon, CRIU, Udica, etc as well as dependencies such as container-selinux bu
                                           ilt and tested together, and updated as frequently as every 12 weeks.         
httpd                2.4 [e]      common,  Apache HTTP Server                                                            
                                  devel, m                                                                               
                                  inimal                                                                                 
javapackages-runtime 201801 [e]   common   Basic runtime utilities to support Java applications                          
mariadb              10.3 [e]     client,  MariaDB Module                                                                
                                  galera,                                                                                
                                  server                                                                                 
nginx                1.14 [e]     common   nginx webserver                                                               
perl                 5.26 [e]     common,  Practical Extraction and Report Language                                      
                                  minimal                                                                                
perl-DBD-MySQL       4.046 [e]    common   A MySQL interface for Perl                                                    
perl-DBI             1.641 [e]    common   A database access API for Perl                                                
perl-IO-Socket-SSL   2.066 [e]    common   Perl library for transparent TLS                                              
perl-libwww-perl     6.34 [e]     common   A Perl interface to the World-Wide Web                                        
php                  remi-7.4 [e] common,  PHP scripting language                                                        
                                  devel, m                                                                               
                                  inimal                                                                                 
python36             3.6 [e]      build, c Python programming language, version 3.6                                      
                                  ommon                                                                                  
ruby                 2.5 [e]      common   An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language                          
subversion           1.10 [e]     common,  Apache Subversion                                                             
                                  server                                                                                 
varnish              6 [e]        common   Varnish HTTP cache                                                            
virt                 rhel [e]     common   Virtualization module
```

How do I remove every module in this list? This should fix things as far as these errors go and then I just need to install the things I want the CentOS 9 way.

Comment: You tried the suggested way? `'--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages`

Comment: In that case it says its skipping the package rhc with broken dependencies and there is nothing else to do. Also the issue with the rhc package is unrelated to all the conflicting request errors above. I just updated the post after removing the rhc package which I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade from Version 7 to 8 the leapp project is used. The AlmaLinux team adapted it for multiple distros and named it ELevate, but it uses the same engine and principles. At the moment, the upgrading from version 8 to 9 is not supported by it, and there are multiple problems:

- The RHEL 8 was very modular when it comes to CentOS Stream 9/RHEL 9/EuroLinux 9 [these are available EL 9 flavours at the moment of writing this post] you won't find many modules. Below is a comparison for CentOS Stream 8 and CentOS Stream 9

CentOS 8 Stream modules:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ yum module list
CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                  2.8 MB/s |  20 MB     00:07    
CentOS Stream 8 - BaseOS                                                                                                                                     8.9 MB/s |  19 MB     00:02    
CentOS Stream 8 - Extras                                                                                                                                      20 kB/s |  18 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                                                               9.2 MB/s |  11 MB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                                                                                       814 kB/s | 1.0 MB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Next - x86_64                                                                                                        196 kB/s | 206 kB     00:01    
CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream
Name                 Stream           Profiles Summary                                                                                                                                       
389-ds               1.4                       389 Directory Server (base)                                                                                                                   
ant                  1.10 [d]         common [ Java build tool                                                                                                                               
                                      d]       
container-tools      rhel8 [d]        common [ Most recent (rolling) versions of podman, buildah, skopeo, runc, conmon, runc, conmon, CRIU, Udica, etc as well as dependencies such as contai
                                      d]       ner-selinux built and tested together, and updated as frequently as every 12 weeks.
container-tools      1.0              common [ Stable versions of podman 1.0, buildah 1.5, skopeo 0.1, runc, conmon, CRIU, Udica, etc as well as dependencies such as container-selinux built
                                      d]        and tested together, and supported for 24 months.
container-tools      2.0              common [ Stable versions of podman 1.6, buildah 1.11, skopeo 0.1, runc, conmon, etc as well as dependencies such as container-selinux built and tested 
                                      d]       together, and supported as documented on the Application Stream lifecycle page.
container-tools      3.0              common [ Stable versions of podman 3.0, buildah 1.19, skopeo 1.2, runc, conmon, etc as well as dependencies such as container-selinux built and tested 
                                      d]       together, and supported as documented on the Application Stream lifecycle page.
container-tools      4.0              common   Most recent (rolling) versions of podman, buildah, skopeo, runc, conmon, runc, conmon, CRIU, Udica, etc as well as dependencies such as contai
                                               ner-selinux built and tested together, and updated as frequently as every 12 weeks.
freeradius           3.0 [d]          server [ High-performance and highly configurable free RADIUS server                                                                                   
                                      d]       
gimp                 2.8 [d]          common [ gimp module                                                                                                                                   
                                      d], deve 
                                      l        
go-toolset           rhel8 [d]        common [ Go                                                                                                                                            
                                      d]       
httpd                2.4 [d]          common [ Apache HTTP Server                                                                                                                            
                                      d], deve 
                                      l, minim 
                                      al       
idm                  DL1              adtrust, The Red Hat Enterprise Linux Identity Management system module                                                                                
                                       client, 
                                       common  
                                      [d], dns 
                                      , server 
idm                  client [d]       common [ RHEL IdM long term support client module                                                                                                      
                                      d]       
inkscape             0.92.3 [d]       common [ Vector-based drawing program using SVG                                                                                                        
                                      d]       
javapackages-runtime 201801 [d]       common [ Basic runtime utilities to support Java applications                                                                                          
                                      d]       
jmc                  rhel8 [d]        common [ Java Mission Control is a profiling and diagnostics tool for the Hotspot JVM                                                                  
                                      d], core 
libselinux-python    2.8              common   Python 2 bindings for libselinux                                                                                                              
llvm-toolset         rhel8 [d]        common [ LLVM                                                                                                                                          
                                      d]       
log4j                2                common   Java logging library                                                                                                                          
mailman              2.1 [d]          common [ Electronic mail discussion and e-newsletter lists managing software                                                                           
                                      d]       
mariadb              10.3 [d]         client,  MariaDB Module                                                                                                                                
                                      galera,  
                                      server [ 
                                      d]       
mariadb              10.5             client,  MariaDB Module                                                                                                                                
                                      galera,  
                                      server [ 
                                      d]       
maven                3.5 [d]          common [ Java project management and project comprehension tool                                                                                        
                                      d]       
maven                3.6              common [ Java project management and project comprehension tool                                                                                        
                                      d]       
mercurial            4.8 [d]          common [ Mercurial -- a distributed SCM                                                                                                                
                                      d]       
mod_auth_openidc     2.3                       Apache module suporting OpenID Connect authentication                                                                                         
mysql                8.0 [d]          client,  MySQL Module                                                                                                                                  
                                      server [ 
                                      d]       
nginx                1.14 [d]         common [ nginx webserver                                                                                                                               
                                      d]       
nginx                1.16             common [ nginx webserver                                                                                                                               
                                      d]       
nginx                1.18             common [ nginx webserver                                                                                                                               
                                      d]       
nginx                1.20             common [ nginx webserver                                                                                                                               
                                      d]       
nodejs               10 [d]           common [ Javascript runtime                                                                                                                            
                                      d], deve 
                                      lopment, 
                                       minimal 
                                      , s2i    
nodejs               12               common [ Javascript runtime                                                                                                                            
                                      d], deve 
                                      lopment, 
                                       minimal 
                                      , s2i    
nodejs               14               common [ Javascript runtime                                                                                                                            
                                      d], deve 
                                      lopment, 
                                       minimal 
                                      , s2i    
nodejs               16               common [ Javascript runtime                                                                                                                            
                                      d], deve 
                                      lopment, 
                                       minimal 
                                      , s2i    
parfait              0.5              common   Parfait Module                                                                                                                                
perl                 5.24             common [ Practical Extraction and Report Language                                                                                                      
                                      d], mini 
                                      mal      
perl                 5.26 [d][e]      common [ Practical Extraction and Report Language                                                                                                      
                                      d], mini 
                                      mal      
perl                 5.30             common [ Practical Extraction and Report Language                                                                                                      
                                      d], mini 
                                      mal      
perl                 5.32             common [ Practical Extraction and Report Language                                                                                                      
                                      d], mini 
                                      mal      
perl-App-cpanminus   1.7044 [d]       common [ Get, unpack, build and install CPAN modules                                                                                                   
                                      d]       
perl-DBD-MySQL       4.046 [d]        common [ A MySQL interface for Perl                                                                                                                    
                                      d]       
perl-DBD-Pg          3.7 [d]          common [ A PostgreSQL interface for Perl                                                                                                               
                                      d]       
perl-DBD-SQLite      1.58 [d]         common [ SQLite DBI driver                                                                                                                             
                                      d]       
perl-DBI             1.641 [d]        common [ A database access API for Perl                                                                                                                
                                      d]       
perl-FCGI            0.78 [d]         common [ FastCGI Perl bindings                                                                                                                         
                                      d]       
perl-IO-Socket-SSL   2.066 [d][e]     common [ Perl library for transparent TLS                                                                                                              
                                      d]       
perl-YAML            1.24 [d]         common [ Perl parser for YAML                                                                                                                          
                                      d]       
perl-libwww-perl     6.34 [d][e]      common [ A Perl interface to the World-Wide Web                                                                                                        
                                      d]       
php                  7.2 [d]          common [ PHP scripting language                                                                                                                        
                                      d], deve 
                                      l, minim 
                                      al       
php                  7.3              common [ PHP scripting language                                                                                                                        
                                      d], deve 
                                      l, minim 
                                      al       
php                  7.4              common [ PHP scripting language                                                                                                                        
                                      d], deve 
                                      l, minim 
                                      al       
php                  8.0              common [ PHP scripting language                                                                                                                        
                                      d], deve 
                                      l, minim 
                                      al       
pki-core             10.6                      PKI Core module for PKI 10.6 or later                                                                                                         
pki-deps             10.6                      PKI Dependencies module for PKI 10.6 or later                                                                                                 
pmdk                 1-fileformat-v6           Persistent Memory Development Kit (former NVML)                                                                                               
pmdk                 1_fileformat_v6           Persistent Memory Development Kit (former NVML)                                                                                               
postgresql           9.6              client,  PostgreSQL server and client module                                                                                                           
                                      server [ 
                                      d]       
postgresql           10 [d]           client,  PostgreSQL server and client module                                                                                                           
                                      server [ 
                                      d]       
postgresql           12               client,  PostgreSQL server and client module                                                                                                           
                                      server [ 
                                      d]       
postgresql           13               client,  PostgreSQL server and client module                                                                                                           
                                      server [ 
                                      d]       
python27             2.7 [d]          common [ Python programming language, version 2.7                                                                                                      
                                      d]       
python36             3.6 [d][e]       build, c Python programming language, version 3.6                                                                                                      
                                      ommon [d 
                                      ]        
python38             3.8 [d]          build, c Python programming language, version 3.8                                                                                                      
                                      ommon [d 
                                      ]        
python39             3.9 [d]          build, c Python programming language, version 3.9                                                                                                      
                                      ommon [d 
                                      ]        
redis                5 [d]            common [ Redis persistent key-value database                                                                                                           
                                      d]       
redis                6                common [ Redis persistent key-value database                                                                                                           
                                      d]       
rhn-tools            1.0 [d]          common [ Red Hat Satellite 5 tools for RHEL                                                                                                            
                                      d]       
ruby                 2.5 [d]          common [ An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language                                                                                          
                                      d]       
ruby                 2.6              common [ An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language                                                                                          
                                      d]       
ruby                 2.7              common [ An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language                                                                                          
                                      d]       
ruby                 3.0              common [ An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language                                                                                          
                                      d]       
rust-toolset         rhel8 [d]        common [ Rust                                                                                                                                          
                                      d]       
satellite-5-client   1.0 [d]          common [ Red Hat Satellite 5 client packages                                                                                                           
                                      d], gui  
scala                2.10 [d]         common [ A hybrid functional/object-oriented language for the JVM                                                                                      
                                      d]       
squid                4 [d]            common [ Squid - Optimising Web Delivery                                                                                                               
                                      d]       
subversion           1.10 [d]         common [ Apache Subversion                                                                                                                             
                                      d], serv 
                                      er       
subversion           1.14             common [ Apache Subversion                                                                                                                             
                                      d], serv 
                                      er       
swig                 3.0 [d]          common [ Connects C/C++/Objective C to some high-level programming languages                                                                           
                                      d], comp 
                                      lete     
swig                 4.0              common [ Connects C/C++/Objective C to some high-level programming languages                                                                           
                                      d], comp 
                                      lete     
varnish              6 [d]            common [ Varnish HTTP cache                                                                                                                            
                                      d]       
virt                 rhel [d][e]      common [ Virtualization module                                                                                                                         
(...)
Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

CentOS Stream 9 modules:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum module list
CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS                                                                                                                                     2.7 MB/s | 5.6 MB     00:02    
CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream                                                                                                                                  4.3 MB/s |  12 MB     00:02    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Thu 17 Mar 2022 03:34:29 PM UTC.
(...) THERE IS NOTHING
```

There were modules in CentOS Stream 9 **, but at the moment [17.03.2022], you won't find any in the AppStream repo** - http://mirror.stream.centos.org/9-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/ - there is no modular data file.

- Another massive problem is that RHEL 8 used Berkeley DB as a backend for RPM when RHEL 9 uses SQLite https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Sqlite_Rpmdb

**To sum it up -> don't jump on the gun with migration from CentOS Stream 8 and CentOS Stream 9. If Red Hat creates some migration scripts (probably based on the LEApp - https://leapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) then it's possible, repeatable and maintainable.**

Comment: Regardless of what is officially supported I would like to hack the upgrade into taking place. I am most of the way there and just have this remaining issue. Surely there is a way?

Comment: I edited the above to show the module list on my system. How do I remove every module in that list? This should fix things as far as these errors go and then I just need to install the things I want the CentOS 9 way.